# Program exits after user input after my switch case

Tags: c++, memory-management

I've been working on an assignment and after writing my code and running it I have noticed that my program exits after my inputting my first user input after my switch case.

I have asked around and found out that is was due to memory allocation on my struct/pointer and have tried initializing new on my int main but it still exits without running the whole program. I am a complete beginner on this and would ask for help.

My code is posted below, any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

This is my declaration of struct & global variables as well as the function where my program exits

```
//struct declaration

struct Students {
    std::string givenName, lastName;
    int         studentType, NumSize, labUnits, lecUnits, totalUnits;
    char        paymentMode;
    long long   courseCode;
};
    
    //Students studs[100]; //global struct declaration
    
    //function prototype
    void
    infoStudent();
    
    void
    studentCode();
    
    void
    computation();
    
    //global variables
    bool inputerror;
    Students stud1;
    Students* studP;
    
    
   
void
infoStudent() {
    
    studP = new Students[size];   //allocates memory 
    delete [] studP;

    std::cout << "\nInput data for Student #" << ctr << ": " << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Student's Last Name: ";
    getline( std::cin, studP[ctr].lastName );

    std::cout << "Student's Given Name: ";
    getline( std::cin, studP[ctr].givenName );

    do {
        std::cout << "Student Number: ";
        std::cin >> studP[ctr].courseCode;
        inputerror = std::cin.fail();

        if ( inputerror || ( studP[ctr].courseCode < 2000000000 || studP[ctr].courseCode > 2999999999 ) ) {
            std::cout << std::endl << "Please enter a proper Student Number." << std::endl << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore( 5, '\n' );
        }
    } while ( inputerror || ( studP[ctr].courseCode < 2000000000 || studP[ctr].courseCode > 2999999999 ) );

    do {
        do {
            std::cout << "Number of Laboratory Units: ";
            std::cin >> studP[ctr].labUnits;
            inputerror = std::cin.fail();

            if ( inputerror || ( studP[ctr].labUnits < 0 || studP[ctr].labUnits > 15 ) ) {
                std::cout << std::endl << "Please enter a proper amount of Laboratory Units." << std::endl << std::endl;
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore( 5, '\n' );
            }
        } while ( inputerror || ( studP[ctr].labUnits < 0 || studP[ctr].labUnits > 15 ) );

        do {
            std::cout << "Number of Lecture Units: ";
            std::cin >> studP[ctr].lecUnits;
            inputerror = std::cin.fail();

            if ( inputerror || ( studP[ctr].lecUnits < 0 || studP[ctr].lecUnits > 15 ) ) {
                std::cout << std::endl << "Please enter a proper amount of Lecture Units." << std::endl << std::endl;
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore( 5, '\n' );
            }
        } while ( inputerror || ( studP[ctr].lecUnits < 0 || studP[ctr].lecUnits > 15 ) );

        studP[ctr].totalUnits = studP[ctr].labUnits + studP[ctr].lecUnits;

        if ( studP[ctr].totalUnits <= 15 ) {
            std::cout << std::endl << "You have " << studP[ctr].totalUnits << " Total Units.\n";
        } else if ( studP[ctr].totalUnits > 15 ) {
            std::cout << std::endl
                      << "Please enter a proper amount of Laboratory and Lecture Units.\n(Must not exceed over 15 units.)\n"
                      << std::endl;
        }
    } while ( studP[ctr].totalUnits > 15 );

    do {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Mode of Payment ([F/f] Full or [I/i] Installment): ";
        std::cin >> (studP[ctr].paymentMode );;
        studP[ctr].paymentMode = std::tolower( studP[ctr].paymentMode );

        if ( studP[ctr].paymentMode == 'f' ) {
            std::cout << "Your chosen Mode of Payment is Full" << std::endl;
        } else if ( studP[ctr].paymentMode == 'i' ) {
            std::cout << "Your chosen Mode of Payment is Installment" << std::endl;
        }

        if ( studP[ctr].paymentMode != 'f' && studP[ctr].paymentMode != 'i' ) {
            std::cout << std::endl << "Please enter a proper mode of payment." << std::endl;
        }

    } while ( studP[ctr].paymentMode != 'f' && studP[ctr].paymentMode != 'i' );
}
```

Comment: Too much code. Please read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: @Mark Please send only the codes you think you have problems. Posting too many codes makes it difficult for people who want to help you to find the problem and focus on the solution.

Comment: `studP = new Students[size]; delete [] studP;` - Um....?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comments, I am fairly new here and I would take these suggestions in mind on my future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating `studP` and then you immediately free the memory. After that you have a dangling pointer and then you are using this invalid pointer (all in function `infoStudent`).

I have to mention that you have a switch-case and you call the same function with no arguments in every case, so this is pointless.

I should also mention, that you have several magic numbers in your code and you shouldn't use global variables that way. Also be sure to initialize all variables.

Comment: hello, thanks, I should just remove the delete portion then just make sure to initialize my variables? ok thanks a lot!

Comment: no not just remove this `delete` section. You have to place it on the right place so you make sure to have no memory leaks.

Comment: ok I will keep this in mind, thanks a lot!

Comment: I would appreciate that you accept this as answer, so this thread can be closed, or others can see that it has been answered.

Comment: sorry for that, i forgot that it was needed, thank you for the comment!